# Highcharts show only particular ticks when large number of x-axis ticks

Tags: highcharts

My Bubble Chart - https://jsfiddle.net/cm4fortp/

Here in this chart I am showing data of last 3 months. The problem is due to width, Highcharts is wrapping up the x-axis ticks i.e. showing only few x-axis labels. I want to show the label for every first date of month and also on 2-weeks interval.

I have used following formatter to play with x-axis labels but not all indexes are coming here.

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if(this.value!=-1 && this.value!=0){

                     console.log(this.value); //to print all the x-axis index

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for maybe something that can give me all the x-axis index or can force Highcharts to display all x-axis labels or something horizontal scroll so that I can increase and fix the width of chart to show all labels.

Comment: Have you considered using `xAxis.tickPositions` - an array defining where the ticks are laid out on the axis? Docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Thanks! It worked. You can put this as answer and I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: Ok I've added the answer, thanks;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show as many ticks as you want you can use `xAxis.tickPositions` - an array defining where the ticks are laid out on the axis.

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions